# Google script for saving attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, email-attachments

I have a file that comes in daily to a Gmail account that I would like to find all of them and extract en excel file attachment to a google drive.

I have tried the following:

```
function saveRatings() {
  
  var searchParams = {
    sender: "##Email adress here##",
    folderName: "Ratings File" ,
       attachName: "SB.xlsx" ,
   };
   
 
// Check if the folder exists
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(searchParams.folderName);
  var folder;
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    // The folder already exists
    folder = folders.next();
    Logger.log("Folder already exists: " + folder.getName());
  } else {
    // The folder does not exist, so create it
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(searchParams.folderName);
    Logger.log("Folder does not exist: " + folder.getName());
  }

 // Get the list of all emails in the inbox that are sent by the specified sender
  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:" + searchParams.sender );
  
  // get the messages in the threads
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  
  Logger.log("Looping through " + messages.length + "mails");

    // Loop through all the messages 
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var attachments = messages[j].getAttachments();
        
        // Loop through all the attachments
        for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
          var attachment = attachments[k];
          
          // Check if the attachment is an Excel file
          if (attachment.getName().endsWith("SB.xlsx")) {
            // Save the attachment to the specified folder
            folder.createFile(attachment);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when running it i get the following error

```
TypeError: messages[j].getAttachments is not a function
saveRatings @ Code.gs:33
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74866952/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: HI, apologies for the delay in getting back but its been the holidays. Yes that's fixed it so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
function saveRatings() {
  var searchParams = {
    sender: "##Email adress here##",
    folderName: "Ratings File",
    attachName: "SB.xlsx",
  };
 
// Check if the folder exists
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(searchParams.folderName);
  var folder;
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    // The folder already exists
    folder = folders.next();
    Logger.log("Folder already exists: " + folder.getName());
  } else {
    // The folder does not exist, so create it
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(searchParams.folderName);
    Logger.log("Folder does not exist: " + folder.getName());
  }

 // Get the list of all emails in the inbox that are sent by the specified sender
  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:" + searchParams.sender );
  
  // get the messages in the threads
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  
  Logger.log("Looping through " + messages.length + "mails");

    // Loop through an array of arrays of messages
    for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
        var attachments = messages[i][j].getAttachments();
        
        // Loop through all the attachments
        for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
          var attachment = attachments[k];
          
          // Check if the attachment is an Excel file
          if (attachment.getName().endsWith("SB.xlsx")) {
            // Save the attachment to the specified folder
            folder.createFile(attachment);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**References:**

[getMessagesForThreads(threads)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagesforthreadsthreads) - this returns `GmailMessage[][]` an array of arrays of messages

[Class GmailAttachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment)